# Irreps of symmetric group: Are projection operators always elements of the group algebra?

Tags: operators, group-theory, representation-theory

In the past, I studied the irreps of the symmetric group using chapter 5 and Appendix III of Wu-Ki Tung's book "Group Theory in Physics." I always thought that the reason that the theory used the idempotents,  which are elements of the group algebra, instead of just basing the theory on the projection operators without introducing the group algebra, was because a projection operator might not be an element of the group algebra. Wu-Ki Tung does not say this, but why else go to the trouble of introducing the idempotents if all the properties of idempotents are simply properties of projection operators? I convinced myself that a projection operator might not be an element of the group algebra by the following argument.

Let the vector space of the regular rep be spanned by basis vectors $|a,i,u\rangle$ where "a" labels the inequivalent irreps, "i" labels states within irrep "a" and "u" labels copies of irrep "a". Set up a projection operator $P_{au}$ onto the irreducible subspace $(a,u)$ as,
\begin{equation}
P_{au}=\sum_{i}|a,i,u\rangle\langle a,i,u|
\end{equation}
The regular rep also has basis vectors $|g\rangle$ for $g\in G$ where $G$ is the group. A general vector is,
\begin{equation}
|x\rangle=\sum_{g\in G}|g\rangle\langle g|x\rangle
\end{equation}
This vector can be changed into an element of the group algebra as,
\begin{equation}
x=\sum_{g\in G}D(g)\langle g|x\rangle
\end{equation}
where $D(g)$ is the rep of $g$. If the projection operator belongs to the group algebra then,
\begin{equation}
P_{au}=\sum_{i}|a,i,u\rangle\langle a,i,u|=\sum_{g\in G}D(g)\langle g|x\rangle
\end{equation}
Now form the diagonal elements of the matrix form of these operators,
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i}\langle h|a,i,u\rangle\langle a,i,u|h\rangle=\sum_{g\in G}\langle h|D(g)|h\rangle\langle g|x\rangle=
\sum_{g\in G}\langle h|gh\rangle\langle g|x\rangle=
\sum_{g\in G}\delta^{h}_{gh}\langle g|x\rangle=\langle 1|x\rangle
\end{equation}
The extreme LHS depends on $h\in G$ whilst the extreme RHS is a constant. Thus I concluded that projection operators are not always elements of the group algebra.

However, some projections operators can be elements of the group algebra. For example, equation (4.2-1) on page 56 of Wu-Ki Tung defines the projection operator,
\begin{equation}
P_{ai}^{j}=\frac{n_{a}}{N}\sum_{g\in G}[D^{(a)}(g^{-1})]^{i}_{\ j}D(g)
\end{equation}
which is clearly an element of the group algebra. In this projection operator $j$ labels copies of irrep $a$. The copies are mixed up in a different way to those labelled by $u$ in the earlier projection operator.

In spite of my argument that projection operators are not necessarily elements of the group algebra, I found the following link,  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3927195/
which, I think, says that every projection operator (indeed every operator) can be in the group algebra.

In summary, my question is, "Are all projection operators in the group algebra?" If possible, I would prefer that this question is not vectored to math.stackexchange.com as I find it hard to understand pure mathematicians' writing on representation theory; Wu-Ki Tung is much easier going than Fulton and Harris!

Comment: What is a « projection operator »? Do you mean by that the projection on some irreducible subspace? Can your question be rephrased as « for all unitary representation of the symmetric group, for all irreducible subspace, is the orthogonal projection onto the subspace in the group algebra?

Comment: @Plop : Yes, by projection I mean projection onto an irreducible subspace. Since the group algebra is defined using the regular rep and the regular rep is unitary, then my question can be re-framed in your way.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my question, "Are all projection operators in the group algebra?" seems to be "No, in general projection operators are not in the group algebra." I'm still a little hesitant here because I don't understand the technicalities of the math.stackexchange.com link in my question which appears to say that all projection operator are in the group algebra. However, if I had not noticed the math.stackexchange.com post, I would not have had any worries about asserting that projection operators are not, in general, in the group algebra. However, the argument I offered for this assertion in my question is flawed and I'll correct it in the following.

The projection operator $P_{au}$ commutes with the operators $D(g)$ of the group rep. So, $D(g)P_{au}=P_{au}D(g)$. This can be proved by inserting a resolution of unity,
\begin{equation}
\sum_{aiu}|a,i,u\rangle\langle a,i,u|=1
\end{equation}
and noting that the group matrices are block-diagonal on the irreps,
\begin{equation}
\langle a,i,u|D(g)|b,j,v\rangle=[D^{(a)}(g)]^{i}_{\ j}\delta^{a}_{b}\delta^{u}_{\ v}
\end{equation}
The action of a projection operator on a vector of the regular rep is now,
\begin{equation}
P_{au}|g\rangle=P_{au}D(g)|1\rangle=D(g)P_{au}|1\rangle=D(g)|e_{au}\rangle
\end{equation}
where the idempotent $e_{au}$, which is in the group algebra, is defined as the vector $|e_{au}\rangle=P_{au}|1\rangle$ and $1 \in G$ is the identity element in the group $G$. The vector $|e_{au}\rangle$ is promoted to a quantity $e_{au}$ in the group algebra exactly as $|x\rangle$ got promoted to $x$ in my question. This shows, as stated by Wu-Ki Tung in section III.3 on the bottom of page 309 of "Group Theory in Physics", that the action of a projection operator $P_{au}$ is realized by *right multiplication* with the idempotent $e_{au}$. This was always the delicate point for me in the construction of the irreps of the symmetric group; why do we need to introduce the idempotents $e_{au}$ in the group algebra when the projection operators $P_{au}$ appear to be adequate tools for the task? The answer seems to be that the projection operators $P_{au}$ are not in the group algebra, but the equation $P_{au}|g\rangle=D(g)|e_{au}\rangle$ is a neat way to get all the power of the projection operators by right multiplication by the idempotents.

To show that the projection operators are not in the group algebra, the projection operator would have to be in the form,
\begin{equation}
P_{au}=\sum_{g\in G}c_{g}D(g)
\end{equation}
where the $c_{g}$ are complex coefficients. To solve for the $c_{g}$ make it into a vector equation $P_{au}|1\rangle=\sum c_{g}|g\rangle$ so that the coefficients are $c_{g}=\langle g|P_{au}|1\rangle$. The projection operator should now have the form,
\begin{equation}
P_{au}=\sum_{g\in G}\langle g|P_{au}|1\rangle D(g)
\end{equation}
The action on a vector of the regular rep is,
\begin{equation}
P_{au}|h\rangle=\sum_{g\in G}\langle g|P_{au}|1\rangle |gh\rangle
=\sum_{k\in G}\langle kh^{-1}|P_{au}|1\rangle |k\rangle
\end{equation}
The correct action of $P_{au}|h\rangle$ is,
\begin{equation}
P_{au}|h\rangle=D(h)P_{au}|1\rangle=\sum_{g\in G}|hg\rangle\langle g|P_{au}|1\rangle
=\sum_{k\in G}|k\rangle\langle h^{-1}k|P_{au}|1\rangle
\end{equation}
The two actions only agree if $\langle kh^{-1}|P_{au}|1\rangle=\langle h^{-1}k|P_{au}|1\rangle$ which implies $kh^{-1}=h^{-1}k$ so G must be Abelian. Since this is not true in general, the conclusion must be that the projection operators are not always in the group algebra. The flaw in my argument in my question was that the matrix element $\langle k|P_{au}|h\rangle=\langle h^{-1}k|P_{au}|1\rangle$ which means that the matrix elements are constant along the diagonal. In the argument in the question, I did not exploit the fact that $P_{au}$ and $D(g)$ commute. The reason that the projection operator $P_{ai}^{j}$ in the question is an element of the group algebra is because it does not commute with the operators $D(g)$ of the regular rep so the above argument does not apply to it.

Answer (score 0):

I’m assuming the question is: for all irreducible subspace of a unitary representation of the symmetric group, is the orthogonal projection operator on it in the group algebra?

For some notation, let us consider a representation $\rho : G \rightarrow U(H)$. Strictly speaking, the group algebra of $G$ is just the set of formal sums $\sum_g a_g g$. To say that some operator $T$ on $H$ is « in the group algebra » means that there are complex numbers $a_g$ (for all $g$ in $G$) such that $T= \sum_g a_g \rho(g)$.

The answer to the general question above is no. Take the direct sum of two copies of the trivial representation. Any line is an irreducible subrepresentation, however, all elements in the group algebra are homotheties, so have rank $0$ or $2$, and therefore cannot be a projection operator on a line.

In a previous version of this answer, I had not understood that the question was about the regular representation of the group. The precise statement that allows to answer the original question is the following. Let $G$ a group, let $\rho : G \rightarrow U(H)$ an irreducible representation. Consider the direct sum representation $\rho_2 : G \rightarrow U(H\oplus H)$ such that for all $v_1,v_2,g$, we have $\rho_2(g)(v_1,v_2) = (\rho(g)(v_1), \rho(g)(v_2))$. Then the projection $P : H \oplus H$ on the first sum and is not in the group algebra. Indeed, consider the operator $D := (v_1,v_2) \mapsto v_1 - v_2$. Then, by definition, for all $v,g$, $D(\rho_2(g)(v, v)) = 0$. However, for all $v$, $D(P(v)) = v$. So $P$ cannot be a linear combination of operators of the form $\rho_2(g)$. This means that if an irreducible subrepresentation of some representation is such that the projection operator on it is in the group algebra, then the multiplicity of it in the representation is one. In particular, for any finite group that has at least one irreducible representation of dimension at least two (those groups are exactly the nonabelian ones), the regular representation has projections that are not in the group algebra.

However, it is true for any « primary » subspace. A primary subspace is a stable subspace such that all of its irreducible subrepresentations are isomorphic to some irreducible representation that does not appear in the decomposition of the orthogonal complement of the subspace. Thus, the primary subspaces are the ones obtained from a full decomposition and grouping the isomorphic irreducible subrepresentations together. One way to prove that the projection operators on such subspaces is in the group algebra can be done using von Neumann bicommutant theorem: it is easily seen (with Schur’s lemma) that an operator that commutes with all group elements must stabilize the primary subspaces; therefore, since the projection operators on the primary subspaces commute with every operator that stabilizes the primary subspaces, every projection operator on a primary subspace is in the bicommutant of the group algebra, hence in the group algebra. Note that this works for arbitrary groups and finite-dimensional representations.

Comment: The number of copies of an irrep of the regular rep is equal to the dimension of the irrep. Since the trivial irrep is 1-d there is only one copy of the trivail irrep, so I think this invalidates your argument in your second paragraph. However, I'm interested in how you prove that an element of the group algebra has rank 0 or 2?

Comment: No… The dimension is the multiplicity in the regular representation, but you can build representations with arbitrary multiplicities.

Comment: Ah, I didn’t understand that you were talking about the regular representation only. I will rephrase.

Comment: For the statement about rank $0$ or $2$, it was only valid for my example. It is just the fact that a multiple of the identity matrix of size $2$ has rank $0$ or $2$.